# Rails 6 - 301 moved permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, puma, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Our rails application uses Rails Web Server - Puma (version `4.3.7`) and
Rails ( version `6.1.3`). The application is started by the command `rails s --binding=0.0.0.0`
But in the browser , when I hit `http://localhost:3000` it returns `301 moved permanently` and redirects to the URL which has hostname  of the machine.  Same thing is observed while accessing the APIs in this app.

This is becoming a blocker running the app in kubernetes environment. The app runs fine in the container but inside the container when I access the app by `wget localhost:3000` it returns `301`.
Can you please help me to fix this issue.

```
anupam:app$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://li-376d8bcc-2115-11b2-a85c-9b485751a7c9.ibm.com:3000/">here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to curl inside the container that is already running the server?

Comment: What happens if you follow the "3000" with a slash?  `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

Comment: You could try `-L` in the curl command to follow redirects.  `curl -L http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: @MarlinPierce  curl -L follows the redirects and works. But I want the app bind to the 127.0.0.1 or localhost .

Comment: If the `-L` worked then the URL it redirected to will work.  From the response it looks like the `/` at the end of the URL is missing.  Try calling `curl` with `-Si` to get more output from the response.  `curl -Si http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

Comment: @MarlinPierce
anupam:cloud_fly$ curl -Si http://127.0.0.1:3000
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://li-376d8bcc-2115-11b2-a85c-9b485751a7c9.ibm.com:3000/
Content-Length: 247

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://li-376d8bcc-2115-11b2-a85c-9b485751a7c9.ibm.com:3000/">here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
Its giving same response

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the application was binding to the hostname of the container rather than `localhost`. Particularly `Rack::CanonicalHost` middleware was setting the hostname to the hostname of the container. Changing that helped me to resolve the issue. In short I changed the following line in `config.ru`

`use Rack::CanonicalHost, ENV['HOSTNAME'] if ENV['HOSTNAME'].present?`

to

`use Rack::CanonicalHost, ENV['RAILS_HOSTNAME'] if ENV['RAILS_HOSTNAME'].present?`

And it resolved the issue.